# Online Molecular Mechanics energy evaluation tool

Tags: resource-recommendations, software, molecular-dynamics

Is there a tool (preferably a website) that will evaluate the energy of my molecule in a given molecular mechanics force field (say Amber or Charmm)? I would like to do the evaluation for a small molecule as butane in vacuum just to see how it goes, observe the rotational energy barrier etc.

Comment: I doubt it. What's wrong with just quickly running the calculation locally?

Comment: I don't have anything set up. I would like to avoid that hassle, that's why I'm looking for an online tool

Comment: @tnorgd: Sorry to see this didn't get any answers, and your question about AMBER force field got closed. They would be completely on topic on my [Materials Modeling](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=NzE1MWZiMjg1NmE1MDU4YWQ2ODkzMzZiNGY5OTRkNWRhN2JkNzdhZGUwODllOWUxNGNjZjRhZjBmYTE3M2M4ZBljSouiYXUzpNjPv6N_DNmpFSwSGHCb4w8-XBwHc-_E0) proposal which covers MD, QM/MM, VASP, and the study of materials like solar cells, photo-voltaics, energy storage materials, new developments in batteries,

Comment: and lighter or stronger materials for cars, airplanes, spaceships, etc. It would be very lovely to have you in the Private Beta! Please commit if you don't think it would be inconvenient!